# Global Object State and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, qliksense

I am using the latest version of Vue.js and I need to use a global object for sharing state in Single Page Vue components. What I'm trying to do is storing the state from a websocket connection in a global object so I can perform actions in Vue.

The problem is that the object is always undefined in Vue.js, but I can clearly see in the browser that the object is populated and have the correct data.

It works using `Obj.$set()` and adding every single property, but I don't want to do that since I don't know all properties beforehand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43193455/7636961

Comment: Consider using VUEX (https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html). This is what vuejs recommends for a shared centalized state

Comment: @wostex inappropriate place to ask but you are the only one I keep seeing answering vuejs related questions...can you help me out with this(http://stackoverflow.com/q/43735371/7814783)

Comment: I even tried to move out the shared object to an external script, it is still undefined in vue components. The link above does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global data with VueJs 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193409/global-data-with-vuejs-2)