# Vuejs: Lifecycle hooks of child routerview components using keep alive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'll explain my issue in a more generalized way for the purpose of clear understanding and here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o01afgy2/)

I have two main routes which show two different components in the `router-view`

- **Route-1** when clicked the path is: '/route-1'
- **Route-2** when clicked the path is: '/route-2/sub-route-a'

**Route-2** contains a another `router-view` inside it which displays two sub routes that are:

- **sub-route-a**
- **sub-route-b**

When **Route-2** is clicked it opens the component of **Route-2** with **sub-route-a** pre-opened in its `router-view`

Both the main router-view and the router-view inside **Route-2** are wrapped inside `keep-alive` tag so that they are cached

Caching and everything works fine as expected.

I added all the lifecycle hooks and using console.log to see which hook is called

- For the first time for all components as expected the `beforeCreate()` , `created()`, `beforeMount()`, `mounted()` hooks are called.
- since the router-view is under `keep-alive` element the `activated()` hook is also called
- whenever I move to and fro between **Route-1** and **Route-2** the `activated()` and `deactivated()` hooks are called when entered and left respectively for each component

Here comes my problem

- Since when **Route-2** is clicked it opens the component of
  **Route-2** with **sub-route-a** pre-opened in its `router-view`, all lifecycle hooks of **sub-route-a** componenents are called only once
- when I go back to **Route-1** `deactivated()` of **Route-2** is called but no hook of **sub-route-a** is called.
- only when I toggle between **sub-route-a** and **sub-route-b** the `activated()` and `deactivated()` hooks of these components are called
- on subsequent entering of **Route-2** `activated()` hook of **Route-2** is called but no hook of **sub-route-a** is called
- I want to cache **sub-route-a** but make changes to it on every enter. So where do I put the code since no lifecycle hook is being called excrpt for the first time.
- **I don't want to use ** `beforeEnter()`

Comment: How about using watch on route inside your sub-route-a?

Comment: @Deepak that could be a workaround,,,but I don't know wby the lifecycle hook are not being called, and watch is more expensive

Comment: So I tried doing the step 1 and 2 of your problems in the provided fiddle. And when I am switching between R1 and R2, SUB-ROUTE A: deactivated and SUB-ROUTE A: activated is actually getting logged.

Comment: @Deepak but I get only activated and deactivated of route-1 and route-2, but not sub-route-a. The activated and deactivated of sub-route-a are called only onve when the app is run for the first time and then after not gettng logged

Comment: SUB-ROUTE A's activated hook is getting called every time I switch between RouteA and RouteB. I just checked the fiddle you have provided.

Comment: @Deepak my bad....its getting called for the fiddle,,but actually i am using webpack...there the log does not show up....thank you for trying out again and correcting me.....I also checked if I had any typos in myvwebppack code...but nothing , its the same as the fiddle,,,,can't figure out whats wrong

Comment: Try building your app and see if it works. You can update your question for the 'experts'!

Comment: @Deepak building the app?,,,,sorry did'nt understand what you said

Comment: npm run build and run that app and debug it.

Comment: @Deepak ya i ran the app that's why i can see the console log statements

Comment: @Deepak i have even posted for help on the vue forum ( https://forum.vuejs.org/t/keep-alive-working-in-jsfiddle-but-not-webpack/10413 ) . You can get the links for the webpack file over there which you could download and test it if you are willing to..thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your vue version to 2.2.0 or greater. The fiddle has 2.3.2, the latest one. And your local version is 2.1.0.

> In 2.2.0 and above, activated and deactivated will fire for all nested
> components inside a  tree.

Read here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Update using: `npm update --save vue`