# How to pass a javascript object to component in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

The question may sound basic, but I am unable to figure out how to do it in VueJS

I have the following in html

```
<script>
 var config = {'cols':4,'color':'red'}
</script>

<div id="app">
   <mycomponent :config="config"></mycomponent>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
      // config: config // I do not want to pass this
   }
})
```

Following is the use case:

- I know this isn't working because config variable in the component is looking for app.config
- I do not want to pass it as `data{ config:config }` in the Vue Object.
- I can pass it as `<mycomponent :config="{'cols':4,'color':'red'}"></mycomponent>` but the config is going to be very long and this would be my last option.
- And yes, this config does not change once the page loads, so I do not need to bind values.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: ++, I did this defining some global `my_componentname_config()` function which gets then invoked within the "created" hook. But its not a neat solution ...

Comment: Passing as a object string to component would be better, also the constraint is that i use this component in multiple places in my app, all I do is change the config.  The config gets generated in backend and is passed along with HTML.

Comment: Make a plugin as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43193455/7636961 at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a global member to Vue itself. **Update:** As Osuwariboy noted in the comments, for some reason Vue is not aware of itself by name in the un-minified version of Vue. It requires creating a Vue data item, which I have done below.

```js
var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
      Vue
   },
   components: {
      myComponent: {
        template: '<div>{{config}}</div>',
        props: ['config']
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
 Vue.$config = {'cols':4,'color':'red'}
</script>

<div id="app">
   <my-component :config="Vue.$config"></my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well for me! Can you please help me understand why javascript objects defined outside are not accessible inside app?

Comment: If it were a global variable, it would be accessible, but declared with `var`, it's not global. Rather than wide-open global, I recommend attaching it to the `Vue` global.

Comment: @RoyJ I can't get your solution to work no matter how hard I try. Could you take a look at my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8xt8ye4g/4/) and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Osuwariboy It works if you use the cloudflare cdn of Vue. You can use the 2.3.4 version on cloudflare and it works; the unpkg.com cdn is supposedly 2.3.4, too, but it doesn't work. I cannot explain that.

Comment: @Osuwariboy You can add a `data` for Vue, defining it using the global Vue, and yours works.
https://jsfiddle.net/8xt8ye4g/5/

Comment: @RoyJ you mean instead of `props:['config']` I'd do `data:['config]`? Also, I discovered your solution only works if you include vue.min.js, if you include vue.js, you get my error.

Comment: @RoyJ Nevermind about my question, I missed the link in your comment. However, my comment about using the minified version VS the clear version still stands, whether you use 2.3.3 or 2.3.4