# vuejs configuration: using a global variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

This seems dumb, but I have it setup like this:

in `config/index.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    API_LOCATION: 'http://localhost:8080/api/'
}
```

then in `src/app.js` I have:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueResource);

const App = require("./app.vue");
const home = require("./components/home.vue");
const config = require('../config');
window.config = config;
```

Then in `src/components/home.vue`, I have a script block that uses it like so:

```
<script>
    module.exports = {
        data: function() {
            return {
                obj: null
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            this.$http.get(config.API_LOCAITON + '/call').then(res => {
                // Do some business
            }, res => {
                // Handle some error
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

This works but it strikes me as a bad idea to use `window` to handle an application configuration. What's the more canonical approach here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Import it.

```
<script>
    import config from "../config"

    module.exports = {
        data: function() {
            return {
                obj: null
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            this.$http.get(config.API_LOCATION + '/call').then(res => {
                // Do some business
            }, res => {
                // Handle some error
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Or just the location.

```
<script>
    import { API_LOCATION } from "../config"

    module.exports = {
        data: function() {
            return {
                obj: null
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            this.$http.get(API_LOCATION + '/call').then(res => {
                // Do some business
            }, res => {
                // Handle some error
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: cool, is there a more global approach? Would be using the `config` object in all components and importing each time seems inefficient...

Comment: @Wells This is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43193455/38065) to that previously. It's really as easy as `Vue.protoype.$config = config` in your main script.

Comment: excellent! Is there an argument for `Vue.prototype.$config` versus the `new Vue({data: config})` approach?

Comment: @Wells If you put it on the prototype it will be available in every component via `this.$config` and it will *not* be reactive. If you put it on data you'll have to pass it to components but it will be reactive. In your case, with it basically being a global value, I'd put it on the prototype, or import it as outlined above.

Answer (score 5):

PROD: `config/prod.env.js` append your `VAR='"value"'`

```
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  API_LOCATION: '"https://production URL"'
}
```

DEV: `config/dev.env.js` append your `VAR='"value"'`

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  API_LOCATION: '"http://localhost"'
})
```

Your variable will available in `process.env.API_LOCATION` or 
`process.env.VAR_NAME`

Comment: true if you use webpack, but if you doesn't how do you load dev/prod env?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** Global configuration in Vue is done using the `.env` and `.env.production` files that you create in the route folder of the app (next to package.json)

I can confirm that in Vue using the Vue CLI `.env` file gets loaded automatically when you run `npm run serve`

But keep in mind the following that I checked:

- Variables in the `.env` files have to start with `VUE_APP` prefix to be automatically picked up and available as `process.env.VUE_APP_MYVAR` in the code
- If you're defining JS objects such as 'VUE_APP_MY_OBJECT={a:100}`then you'll have to parse it to JSON before using it in the code`JSON.parse(process.env.VUE_APP_MY_OBJECT)`
- If you're not using Webpack you might have to fiddle a bit with it to pick these config files up. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50831022/617466) it looks like webpack should do it automatically. Dunno

Answer (score -2):

Simply set ip path(or localhost) in local storage when login successfull and get value from local storage where you need through out the project.
here how you set value in localstrage.

`// Set value in IpAdress
localstorage.setItem('IpAddress','192.168.100.100:8080');`

`// Get value from IpAddress
localstorage.getItem('IpAddress');`

in my case whole path looks like:
`localstorage.getItem('IpAddress')+/api/controller/method|`