# VueJS observe plugged parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, object-property

I'm starting with VueJS 2 and I created a simple plugin which adds parameter to Vue instance.

I have problem because when I update this value my computed properties are still same.

My example plugin's code:

```
export default function (Vue) {
    Vue.MyProperty = "test"

    Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
        "$myProperty": {
            "get": function () {
                return Vue.MyProperty
            },

            "set": function (value) {
                Vue.MyProperty = value

                return this
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And my component's code

```
export default {
    "computed": {
        "test": function () {
            return this.$myProperty
        }
    }
}
```

When I changed `this.$myProperty` in other component my component returns vaid value (in example when I changed from `"test"` into `"newvalue"` I can see `"newvalue"`) but computed property `test` is still old value (`"test"` in my example).

I tried to use `this.$set(this, "$myProperty", value)` but this still not working.

How can I use or declare this property to use it in computed or watched properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the data value is not automatically updated in the computed is because the property you added to Vue, `MyProperty` is not an *observed* property. Fundamentally, Vue's reactivity works because all values added to *data* are converted into *observed* properties; under the hood they are converted into getter/setter pairs with some additional code so that when one of those properties *changes*, Vue knows to propagate the changes to all the things that depend on it's value.

The code in the question, however, just adds a normal property to the Vue object. You can change it, but it's not reactive.

That said, it's relatively easy to make it reactive. I cover how to do this in the comments to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43193455/38065). Basically, instead of adding your property to Vue, just create a new Vue object (which has very low overhead) and make the property you want to be reactive a property of that Vue. Here is a working example.

```js
console.clear()

function MyPlugin(Vue) {
  let store = new Vue({data:{MyProperty: "some value"}})

    Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
        "$myProperty": {
            "get": function () {
                return store.MyProperty
            },

            "set": function (value) {
                store.MyProperty = value

                return this
            }
        }
    })
}

Vue.use(MyPlugin)

const MyComponent = {
  template:`<div>{{test}}</div>`,
    "computed": {
        "test": function () {
            return this.$myProperty
        }
    }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components:{
    MyComponent
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
  <button @click="$myProperty = 'new value'">Change</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What can I say -- it's very smart to use second Vue instance :) I found different solution but yours is also clever