# How to get `webpack.config.js` or `vue.config.js` file data globally in VueCLI 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm working on a project which develop by VueCLI `3.0`. I've Created a config file in the root and named as `vue.config.js`. I've defined my custom configuration. but every time I've to load this file in every `component` file to use it. Is there any way or option to get globally in every `js` file and `component`.

> I'm newbie in VueCli.

Here, is my `vue.config.js` file :-

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
      api : {
          server: 'http//:192.168.0.1'
      }
  }
```

In my `App.vue` - I want to access this way.

```
<script>
export default{
  mounted(){
    console.log(api.server)
  }
}
</script>
```

**Please help me out and give suggestions**

Comment: please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828904/using-environment-variables-with-vue-js)

Comment: @PRAJINPRAKASH this not working.

Comment: actually this  `vue.config.js ` is consumed by `vu-cli-service` it does't have any reference inside `vue`, If you want make it simpler do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193409/global-data-with-vuejs-2)

Answer (score 0):

It not recommend to use data in `vue.config.js` directly. If you have some variables based on environment, use [Modes and Environment Variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes).

Comment: Except `ENV` other variables how can i get them.

Answer (score 0):

**Its not recommended method** even if you need to do that just try this.

```
import vueconfig from "./../vue.config.js";
new Vue({
    data:{
        config
    }
})
```

one thing you remember that we can't define custom data in `vue.config.js` see [this](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/) , If you want custom config rename the file.